# How can I authenticate to BPOS SharePoint using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, authentication

Does anyone know where I can find resources explaining how I can authenticate towards BPOS SharePoint using javascript? I have managed to authenticate with Office365 building on the scripts of [lstak](https://github.com/lstak/node-sharepoint), but I have not found resources that explain how to authenticate with BPOS or how this procedure works.